# Проблема передачи указателя на строку

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Передаю `_TCHAR` указатель в функцию

```
void foo(_TCHAR* somestring)
```

где somestring глобально объявленный TCHAR[200],  далее вызываю

```
RegSetValueEx(..., REG_SZ, (BYTE*)somestring, sizeof(somestring));
```

И записывается только первый символ.

Comment: Я в Си не специалист, но знаю что строки в Си это указатели, сами по себе на первый элемент из данных байт. Соответственно простой указатель на строку указывает на первый символ, а для того что бы вывести N-ный символ, нам надо прибавить N к указателю, пример 

`char* str = "Helllo"; 
cout << (*str) += 1 << endl; // e `

Comment: Написана какие-то белиберда. Что значит "somestring глобально объявленный TCHAR[200]", когда из вопроса явно видно, что `somestring` - это просто параметр функции `foo` типа `_TCHAR*`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если `somestring` *глобальный*, то его не надо передавать в функцию - он виден и так, потому он и глобальный :) И тогда - если он виден как `TCHAR[200]` - выражение `sizeof(somestring)` будет размером этого массива.

Но когда вы передаете его в функцию как `void foo(_TCHAR* somestring)`, глобальная переменная становится скрыта, и под именем `somestring` в теле функции выступает уже совсем другая переменная - локальный аргумент-указатель. И для него `sizeof(somestring)` - размер не массива, а указателя, со всеми вытекающими последствиями.

Передавайте в функцию `foo` еще и длину для записи в реестр.

Comment: С размером уже разобрался - спасибо. Но теперь еще одна напасть, даже с гвоздями прибитым размером перестала записывать значение, RegSetValueEx возвращает 0х05 Доступ запрещен.

Comment: Это уже не языковая проблема, это у вас, скорее всего, прав туда, куда вы хотите, нет. Куда именно вы пишете? Какие первые параметры `RegSetValueEx`? Еще один вопрос(но, по коду судя, это не он) - это насчет использования Unicode, все ли с этой точки зрения верно.

Comment: перед вызовом процедуры поставил  _tcslen для проверки длинны, и в самой процедуре перед записью также, как только убрал эти проверки все взлетело, наверное вернусь опять на кьют, нет сил на магию..